# how to detect value null in ng-change in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

here's my view

```
md-input-container flex=""
        label Mynumber
        input type="number" ng-model="mynumber" ng-change="checkMynumber(mynumber)" step="0.01" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" string-to-number=""
```

my controller

```
$scope.checkMynumber = (number) =>
  if number?
    alert "true"
  else
    alert "false"
```

when i input my first number it alert True that was right but when i erase my inputed number it keeps alert True. i want to alert false when my input type is null.

Comment: did you checked my answer. your code is working perfectly with directives `string-to-number` also

Comment: you dont have the code of my directives?

Answer (score 2):

```
 $scope.checkMynumber = function (number) {
   if(number) {
     alert(true)
   } else {
     alert(false)
   }
  }
```

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aswathyb950/9jfww52h/

Answer (score 1):

You can use

$scope.checkMynumber = function(number){
    if (number!= null)
       alert "true"
    else
       alert "false"
 }

Comment: it also alert true

Comment: I think your value may be undefined use angular.isUndefined(val) || val === null

Answer (score 1):

remove the ternary operator and stick with the `if else` conditions

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.checkMynumber = function(number) {
  if (number)
    alert("true")
  else
    alert ("false")
    
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input type="number" ng-model="mynumber" ng-change="checkMynumber(mynumber)" step="0.01" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" string-to-number="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29449/)**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkMynumber = function(number) {
    number ? alert("true") : alert("false");  
  }
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <input type="number" ng-model="mynumber" ng-change="checkMynumber(mynumber)" step="0.01" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" string-to-number="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it because of my directives string-to-number thanks guys its working now

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why almost every answer here is in .js instead .coffee, like in question.. anyway you can imporove your code

1. `ng-model="mynumber" ng-change="checkMynumber(mynumber)"` I guess `mynumber` is your scope variable, so why you are passing this to method? (I don't have full  code, but you are using fat arrow there, otherwise I would find reason to pass this as argument)
2. Your method checkMyNumber can be only like this:

   `$scope.checkMynumber =  => alert $scope.mynumber? + ""`